# memory error in python while using counvectorizer() for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, out-of-memory, nltk, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

I am using below code to construct document term matrix in python.

```
# Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


dataset=pd.read_csv("trainset.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
dataset['ProductDescription']=dataset['ProductDescription'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')
dataset['ProductDescription']=dataset['ProductDescription'].str.replace('[\d]', ' ')
dataset['ProductDescription']=dataset['ProductDescription'].str.lower()
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
dataset['ProductDescription']=dataset['ProductDescription'].str.replace(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stop) + r')\b\s*', ' ')
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
x1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset['ProductDescription'].values.astype('U'))
df = pd.DataFrame(x1.toarray().transpose(), index = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

For 10000 dataset the code is working fine but when i consider large dataset of around 1100000, I am getting **memory error** when i execute

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(x1.toarray().transpose(), index = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Can somebody please tell me where i have gone wrong?

Comment: Where are you using this last line? Why? Why are you making a sparse array to dense? Thats the source of error.

Comment: I need to give dense matrix to random forest. I didn't find any implementation of random forest that use sparse matrix.

Comment: Moreover After completion of  x1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset['ProductDescription'].values.astype('U')) ,I am getting memory error for anything I do.

Comment: First, if you are using RandomForestClassifier, then it accepts sparse matrix. Second, try to use a more powerful machine if you can.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar ,Thanks for your response. I am using system with 128GB RAM. After creation of sparse matrix. I am getting memory error , not able to do anything.

Comment: I am not understanding. Can you explain a bit more. As a side note, please dont load whole data inside the dataframe if thats too much space. You can directly supply filename as input to CountVectorizer.